# How do I continue my while loop in relations to quicksort

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, sorting, quicksort

This is my array

```
 numArray: [4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 1, 8, 3]
```

Here I create my pivot element which I chose to be the middle one

```
quickSort(array = this.state.numArray) {

const pivot = array[Math.floor(array.length / 2)]; //pivot = 5
const leftArr = [];
const rightArr = [];
```

next up I created a function that filters bigger and smaller numbers than 5
in the left and right array(smaller numbers in left and bigger in right)No Problem so far..

```
const Partition = () => {
        

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] === pivot) {
                console.log(array[i]);

       

 } else if (array[i] < pivot) {
            leftArr.push(array[i]);
        } else {
            rightArr.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My swap function that, which swaps elements in the array

```
const swap = (items, leftIndex, rightIndex) => {

            let temp = items[leftIndex];
            items[leftIndex] = items[rightIndex];
            items[rightIndex] = temp;
        }
```

Last but not least my sorting function. Problem here is it stops sorting way too early since
the condition of the while loop is already met. How can I structure it so it keeps going till it's sorted?

```
const sort = (items) => {
            let i = 0;
            let j = items.length - 1;
            let newPivot = items[0];
            let sortedArray = items;

    

while (i <= j) {
    

while (sortedArray[i] < newPivot) {
            i++;
        }

        while (sortedArray[j] > newPivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            swap(sortedArray, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;

        }
        console.log(i + " <= " + j);

    }

    return sortedArray;

}
```

Comment: I don't really see where `rightArr` and `leftArr` come into play in the sorting function, furthermore, I don't think your function `sort` has anything to do with sorting, it is just swapping smaller/bigger numbers the the pivot (which is the first element) - You do not reset `i` and `j` thus if we have `[3,5,4,1]` after two iterations it will stop at `[1,5,4,3]`

Comment: isn't that the whole idea behind quicksort? the left and right array are in place for partitioning the array. In my case if you call the sort function twice, it would return the sorted array.
Problem starts with bigger arrays, because the while loop ends too early, which means I need to implement a function which check whether the array is sorted or not and run sort() again if it isn't.
I have seen a bunch of quicksort tutorials, but not once do they reset i and j. They just recursively return the array and swap till the array is sorted.

Comment: No, I don't see quicksort happening here, the idea behind quicksort is to partition each sub-array and call it recursively (or iteratively if possible) - I only see one partition going on and it is not being used because I don't see those two 'sub arrays' (leftArr, rightArr) being merged together - which is not quicksort as quicksort should be in-place (not using any extra space)